# Uncaught TypeError: workouts.map is not a function "react"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

**this is the JSON file that is coming from the server**

```
 {workouts: Array(3)}
workouts: Array(3)
0: {_id: 'idnumber1', title: 'pullup', reps: 40, load: '20', createdAt: '2022-07-20T18:06:39.642Z', …}
1: {_id: 'idnumber2', title: 'situp', reps: 40, load: '20', createdAt: '2022-07-20T10:10:14.078Z', …}
2: {_id: 'idnumber3', title: 'pushup', reps: 10, load: '0', createdAt: '2022-07-19T14:33:58.678Z', …}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

//**this is the code I did in react**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [workouts, setworkouts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fecthworkout = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/api/workout");
      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setworkouts(json);
      }
    };

    fecthworkout();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="workouts">
 
        {workouts &&
          workouts.map((workouts) => (
           <p key={workouts._id}>{workouts.title}</p>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

//**can any tell me how can I stop the error?**

I am stuck here I need help here

I am stuck here I need help here

Comment: Seems that workouts is not an array (it does not have .map method) My guess it's an object with "workouts" property.

Change this: setworkouts(json); ->  setworkouts(json.workouts);

Comment: Use `workouts.workouts.map()`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I believe there's perhaps another layer of nesting before you get to the workouts array inside the json. Anyway, this is what worked for me
setWorkouts(json.workouts)

Looks like paroxyzm was all over this already in the comments which I had not noticed before I gave my response

Answer (score -1):

Your `useState` hook should by default be `useState([])` and not `useState(null)`.